# How to find original number in column1

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

What is the best or most expressive way to write SQL Query  in Snowflake

Need to find original number for that logic is

Column5 = 0 and column1 = 'qw%'

Last 3 digit of that starts with qw = Last 3 digit of the corresponding original number

will have same column2,column3,column4 values

| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4 | Column5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 23 | 11 | 45242 | 7890 |
| qw345 | 23 | 11 | 45242 | 0 |
| 23981 | 56 | 22 | 45243 | 6678 |
| qw981 | 56 | 22 | 45243 | 0 |
| 99765 | 31 | 90 | 45244 | 3345 |
| qw765 | 31 | 90 | 45244 | 0 |
| 44871 | 78 | 45 | 45245 | 2345 |
| qw871 | 78 | 45 | 45245 | 0 |

Sample Output below:

| original_number | col |
| --- | --- |
| 12345 | qw345 |
| 23981 | qw981 |
| 99765 | qw765 |
| 44871 | qw871 |

Comment: I've tried this query : SELECT original_number, col
FROM your_table t1
JOIN your_table t2 ON SUBSTRING(t1.Column1, 4) = SUBSTRING(t2.Column1, 4)
                   AND t1.Column2 = t2.Column2
                   AND t1.Column3 = t2.Column3
                   AND t1.Column4 = t2.Column4
WHERE t1.Column5 = 0
  AND t1.Column1 LIKE 'qw%'
  AND t2.Column5 <> 0;

Answer (score 1):

You need to self-join your table by last 3 digit of column1, then apply conditional aggregation using `GROUP BY` and `MAX()` :

```
select max(case when t.Column1 not like 'qw%' then t.Column1 end) as original_number,
       s.Column1 as col
from your_table t
inner join (
  select Column1
  from your_table
  where Column5 = 0 and column1 like 'qw%'
) s on SUBSTRING(s.Column1, 3) = SUBSTRING(t.Column1, 3)
group by s.Column1;
```